# Can't remove padding from Activity Dialog

Tags: android-layout, xamarin.android, xamarin, android

I have an activity styled as a popup:

```
[Activity(Theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog")]
public class GameOverPopup : Activity
```

But I'm always stuck with a white padding around my controls (ignore the black border, it's not part of the popup):

[image]

I've tried setting the  padding, margin, etc. to 0dp but always have that extra space.

How can I remove it?

**UPDATE:**

So I've tried the following according to suggestions:

In Styles.xml:

```
<style name="PopupDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
   <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
</style>
```

And then in my Activity (in the OnCreate Override):

```
SetTheme(Resource.Style.PopupDialog);
```

Yet I still have the padding  :(

Comment: can we have some code snippet please!!

Comment: I'm not sure what more I can post. The xml for the above popup is regular xml that is irrevelant since it is contained inside the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!!

Problem is that I set the theme in code on the OnCreate AS WELL as an attribute to the activity. So I remove the code from OnCreate and put the following attribute in my popup Activity class:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/PopupDialog")]
public class GameOverPopup : Activity
```

And my Styles.xml is:

```
<style name="PopupDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
  <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, the auto-generated activities in Eclipse include the Android activity-wide margins by default. You might check to make sure you have removed these lines in your XML layout if you used the default template.

**EDIT**, to sum up some comments and avoid creating a discussion: it appears that the problem may be due to the default padding in the dialog box style. Try creating a style with that style as its parent, and manually set the padding/margins as needed: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#DefiningStyles.

Comment: I'm not using Eclipse, this is a Xamarin project. Therefore code is in C# and UI is in regular android XML.

Comment: Ah, indeed, sorry about this. Can you post XML?

Comment: There is no other XML that I can show because the layout of the popup is simply a regular layout using LinearLayouts. The theme I'm referencing is an android theme. I'm wondering if there is code I can add in the activity to manually remove padding?

Comment: If you have checked all attributes that you are in control of, perhaps the dialog theme that you are using is the source of the padding.

Comment: Ok, so how can I edit that dialog theme. Is there a way of overriding the theme values of "android:style/Theme.Dialog" ?

Comment: I believe you can create a theme that uses Theme.Dialog as its parent (should be pretty simple; see [Defining Styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#DefiningStyles))